# how to send scope variable in ng-if in li element?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how to send scope variable in ng-if in li element? i have one li that i need to change according to the scope variable.if value is true it should show different li.
html code

```
<h4 class="font-weight-normal mb-3">
    Light Status
    <i ng-if="{{offbulbstatus}}" class="mdi mdi-lightbulb mdi-24px float-right"></i>
    <i ng-if="{{onbulbstatus}}" class="mdi mdi-lightbulb-on mdi-24px float-right"></i>
</h4>
```

javascript

```
 if($scope.lightstatus =="ON"){
     $scope.onbulbstatus= true;
     $scope.offbulbstatus=false;
 }
 else {
     $scope.onbulbstatus= false;
     $scope.offbulbstatus=true;
 }
```

Comment: Likely the issue is that you're using the strings `"true"` and `"false"` instead of actual booleans. These strings always evaluate to a *truthy* value, so the `ng-if` is never false. You also don't need the `{{ }}`. If that's not it, we can't tell what the problem is from the given sample.

Comment: @deceze is correct. Another important thing to remember with angularjs scopes is that primitives are best not but directly on the scope because their value will not always propagate to child scopes correctly. Best to put such properties in an object as $scope.properties = { onbulbstatus: true, ...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
<h4 class="font-weight-normal mb-3">
    Light Status
    <i class="mdi mdi-lightbulb mdi-24px float-right"
       ng-class="{'mdi-lightbulb': lightstatus !== 'ON', 'mdi-lightbulb-on': lightstatus === 'ON'}"></i>
</h4>
```

Comment: thanks its working in light off status , hope it will work for light status on also

Comment: In the response it is used AngularJS [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)